# Is there a way to use Foxy Proxy or some url pattern in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, proxy, internet-explorer-11

I want to redirect some url pattern to take resources from locally, and same can be achieved using foxy proxy extension in Chrome or Firefox, but there is no support for IE.
Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the FoxyProxy services with Internet Explorer according to [this instruction](https://help.getfoxyproxy.org/index.php/knowledge-base/how-to-use-your-proxy-services-with-internet-explorer/).

Or you could manually set proxy settings in IE through **Internet Options**: In the **Connections** tab, click **LAN settings**, tick **Use a proxy server for your LAN** and enter the proxy server address and port. You could refer to [this article](https://www.wikihow.com/Enter-Proxy-Settings-in-Internet-Explorer) for detailed steps.

Comment: Thanks, Yu for the help, I tried these instructions, as this change will redirect all the calls to local, but what I need is to redirect specific URL pattern to load resources from local.

Comment: We can only except some urls using [this setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S48GP.jpg) but seems can't only redirect any specific url. I didn't find plugin like this and there's not such setting in IE. So I think the answer is there's not such a way.

Comment: Correct, that is the reason I wanted to know any suggestions on this IE issue?
But yeah anyways, thanks for your help

Comment: Hi @Yu Zhou, I think this can be solved using Fiddler,
steps are mentioned below
Download and install Fiddler from https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler.
Open Fiddler, Go to AutoResponder tab
Check 'Enable Rules' and 'Unmatched requests passthrough' checkboxes.
Click on 'Add Rule' button and add your rule/s, following is a sample rule

Comment: Yes, it works! You could post the solution as an answer and mark it as an accepted answer after 48hrs when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for informing me of the solution.